# Issue in copying rows based on certain conditions in Vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Set ws4 = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
Lastrowto = ws4.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For y = Lastrowto To 1 Step -1
    If ws4.Cells(y, "B").Value = "Not found" Then
        ws4.Rows(y).EntireRow.Copy
    End If
Next y
```

The above piece of vba code copies only 1 (the first one) row but I want to copy all those rows for which the given condition is met, kindly suggest me the correct version of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ***Copy>>Paste*** one row at a time, which will take a long time to process, you can use a `Range` object named `CopyRng`.

Every time the criteria is met (`If .Range("B" & y).Value = "Not found"`), it will add the current row to `CopyRng`.

After finishing looping through all your rows, you can just copy the entire rows at once using `CopyRng.Copy`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyMultipleRows()

Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Dim Lastrowto As Long, y As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range

Set ws4 = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets(1)

With ws4
    Lastrowto = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For y = Lastrowto To 1 Step -1

        If .Range("B" & y).Value = "Not found" Then
            If Not CopyRng Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRng = Application.Union(CopyRng, .Rows(y))
            Else
                Set CopyRng = .Rows(y)
            End If
        End If

    Next y
End With

' copy the entire rows of the Merged Range at once
If Not CopyRng is Nothing Then CopyRng.Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: Much nicer and more efficient way of doing things! And OP only needs to specify a single paste destination cell as well.

Comment: Thanks but I have tried this code, CopyRng.Copy line gives me an error.

Comment: @yashikavaish try edited code. Unless you have no matches in column B that match your criteria

Comment: The runtime error 464 is coming with CopyRng keyword

Comment: @yashikavaish  not sure what you mean? Did you copy my entire code? Or just sections ? I tested this code and it copies exactly as it should

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to copy it to? if you specify a destination to your copy, then your code could work.

e.g. if you have a destination sheet defined as wsDest, you can replace

```
ws4.Rows(y).EntireRow.Copy
```

by

```
ws4.Rows(y).EntireRow.Copy wsDest.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(1)
```

assuming you always have a value in column 1.

Another option is to do an autofilter on column B, with the value not found, and use the `specialcells` property to copy to another spot. Recording a macro will help you quite a bit, but code will be something like:

```
with ws4.cells(1,1).currentregion
    .autofilter field:=2,criteria1:="Not found"
    .specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).copy
end with
```

Comment: t = 2
   For y = Lastrowto To 1 Step -1
If ws4.Cells(y, "B").Value = "Not found" Then
  ws4.Rows(y).EntireRow.Copy
  Worksheets(2).Select
  ws3.Cells(Lastrowp + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
t = t + 1
  End If
  Next y

Comment: This is my paste code but It only paste one record because single record is being copied while debugging the index y holds all the row values according to condition but copies only 1 that's the issue

Comment: "Not Found" is a string keyword so the second code can't work in this condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying but there is no paste line.

An example, with a paste line destination of `ws1.Cells(counter,"B")`, assuming another worksheet variable `ws1` might be:

```
 ws4.Rows(y).EntireRow.Copy ws1.Cells(counter,"B")
```

See the following where a msgbox shows you each time you are entering loop and have met the condition so are copying:

```
Public Sub test1()

    Dim ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrowto As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim counter As Long

    Set ws4 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ben")
    lastrowto = ws4.Cells(ws4.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'fully qualify
    counter = 0

    For y = lastrowto To 1 Step -1

        If ws4.Cells(y, "B").Value = "Not found" Then
            ws4.Rows(y).EntireRow.Copy 'put paste destination code here e.g. ws1.Cells(counter,"B") where ws1 would be another sheet variable
            counter = counter + 1
            Msgbox counter 'if has entered loop print current count

        End If

    Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: t = 2
   For y = Lastrowto To 1 Step -1
If ws4.Cells(y, "B").Value = "Not found" Then
  ws4.Rows(y).EntireRow.Copy
  Worksheets(2).Select
  ws3.Cells(Lastrowp + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
t = t + 1
  End If
  Next y

Comment: This is my paste code but It only paste one record because single record is being copied while debugging the index y holds all the row values according to condition but copies only 1 that's the issue

Comment: Are you incrementing Lastrowp ? Looks like you are overwriting each time to this same position. Should t actually be LastrowP or is there more code we can't see?

Comment: Also, please edit the code in your question to add this detail rather than in comments.